# For $a,n \in \Bbb N$, how to prove if $a^n-1$ is prime then $a=2$ and $n$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose  $a,n \in \Bbb N $. How do you prove that if $a^n-1$ is prime, then $a=2$ and $n$ is prime .

Is the converse true I.E : (if $p$ is prime then $2^p-1$ is prime)?

Comment: Don't forget $a = 3$, $n = 1$!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n=1,a-1$ will be prime $=p$(say) if $a=p+1$ where $p$ is any prime.

For $n>1,$

As here $(a-1)\mid(a^n-1)$

$a-1$ must be $<2\implies a=2$

Now, if $n=rs$ where $r,s$ are integers$>1$,

$(a^r-1)\mid (a^{rs}-1)\implies a^n-1$ can not be prime

So, the necessary condition for $a^n-1$ be prime are $a=2$ and $n$ is prime.

The converse is not true as for example $2^p-1$ is not prime for $p=11$

This using $3$rd theorem of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers), if prime $q\mid(2^p-1), 2p\mid(q-1)$ i.e., $q=2\cdot k\cdot p+1$ where integer $k\ge0$

For $p=11, q=22k+1$ and we can verify $2^{11}-1=23\cdot89$

Reference: [List of known Mersenne primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#List_of_known_Mersenne_primes)

Comment: Notice that, when $a$ is odd, $a^n-1$ is even, thus =$2$, i.e. $a=3, n=1$. Otherwise this proof is perfect.

Comment: @awllower, for $n=1,$ if $a=p+1$ where $p$ is any prime, $a=p$(prime). I think, I should include the assumption that integer $n>1$

Comment: It is always a good thing to improve upon the completeness, at least from my point of view. Thanks for the answer BTW.

Comment: @awllower, agreed and consummated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You will find that $23$ divides $2^{11}-1$.

For much more, search for **Mersenne prime.** From the computations that have been done, $2^p-1$ is composite for "most" primes $p$. The finding of a Mersenne prime is a fairly rare event. But it just happened again recently.