# A Problem with primes of the form $2^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that if $2^n-1$ is prime, then $n$ is prime.

I could not see a way to a direct proof based on the definition of a prime number. In that case, we could only write $2^n-1$ as $1 \cdot (2^n-1)$, and I don't see how that would help.

I think the best way to go about this proof is to use the contrapositive of the statement, which I believe is "if $n$ is not prime, then $2^n-1$ is not prime". So, if $n$ is not prime, it is composite and can be factored into the form $ab$. We plug that into $2^n-1$ to get $2^{ab}-1$. Now, if either $a$ or $b$ is even, we could use the laws of exponents and the difference of two squares to get a factored form and therefore prove that $2^n-1$ is composite. The problem in this approach is showing that if both $a$ and $b$ are odd, how the resulting expression can factor. We write this symbolically as $2^{(2k+1)(2m+1)}-1$ for some natural numbers $k$ and $m$. I don't know how to factor this. If anyone sees how to factor this, that would be awesome. Or, if anyone sees a flaw in my approach, that would also be greatly appreciated.

Finally, I ask that y'all **not directly give me the answer**, but rather a powerful hint. I am really trying to learn on my own, and I feel that the struggle will eventually pay off. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $a^n -b^n = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b + \cdots + b^{n-1} )$.

Comment: The following post provides a generalization : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: So, when I got help originally on this problem, he did help me to see that $a^n-1$ can be factored as $(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+...+1)$. However, I noted that in our case, a=2, so (a-1) becomes 1. So, my thought process is that all we did here is multiply by 1, and find a new way to express $2^n-1$ as a sum, and that this doesn't help show that the $2^n-1$ is composite. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use the given hint to show your contrapositive.  As $n=ab$, where both $a,b>1$ then $2^n-1=(2^a)^b-1=(2^a-1)(2^{a(b-1)}+...+1)$

Comment: Ohhh. Thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For $a,n \in \Bbb N$, how to prove if $a^n-1$ is prime then $a=2$ and $n$ is prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328671/for-a-n-in-bbb-n-how-to-prove-if-an-1-is-prime-then-a-2-and-n-is-pri)

Comment: These are called Mersenne primes. See great internet search for Mersenne primes at PrimeNet. Only 49 primes of this type have been found. Not all primes for n necessarily give Mersenne primes; for example for $n=11$ we get $2047=23\times 89$